# What's the function for google calculator's CE button?

Tags: javascript, calculator

I made a basic calculator. I'm trying to mimic google's calculator when deleting an operator, it deletes the empty strings around the operator as well. This is the delete button I have.

```
deletebtn.addEventListener('click', () => {
currentDisplay.textContent = currentDisplay.textContent.slice(0, -1);
})
```

I've tried 'if' statements with split(), replace(), substring() to no avail.

Edit: I wasn't too clear with my calculator. My display shows an expression as 12" "+" "13 with empty spaces before and after each operator. When I clear a previous entry and it gets to the operator, I have to clear the empty spaces and the operator. So, it needs 3 button presses to clear the after-space, operator and before-space.

I want to delete the operator and the 2 empty spaces at the same time with a 'Clear' previous entry button.

Answer (score 0):

You should beware of the display element you use. If `currentDisplay` is `<input>` element then you can use `currentDisplay.value` to get and set the value.

```js
let currentDisplay = document.querySelector('#display');
let deleteBtn = document.querySelector('#delete');
let deleteAllBtn = document.querySelector('#deleteAll');

deleteBtn.addEventListener('click', () => {
  //currentDisplay.textContent = currentDisplay.textContent.slice(0, -1);
  currentDisplay.value = currentDisplay.value.slice(0, -1);
});

deleteAllBtn.addEventListener('click', () => {
  //currentDisplay.textContent = currentDisplay.textContent.slice(0, -1);
  currentDisplay.value = '';
});
```

```html
<input id="display" type="text" value="5+3" />
<button id="delete">C</button>
<button id="deleteAll">CE</button>
```

If `currentDisplay` is not `<input>` element then you can use `currentDisplay.textContent` to get and set the value.

```js
let currentDisplay = document.querySelector('#display');
let deleteBtn = document.querySelector('#delete');
let deleteAllBtn = document.querySelector('#deleteAll');

deleteBtn.addEventListener('click', () => {
  currentDisplay.textContent = currentDisplay.textContent.slice(0, -1);
  //currentDisplay.value = currentDisplay.value.slice(0, -1);
});

deleteAllBtn.addEventListener('click', () => {
  currentDisplay.textContent = '';
  //currentDisplay.value = currentDisplay.value.slice(0, -1);
});
```

```html
<span id="display">5+3</span>
<button id="delete">C</button>
<button id="deleteAll">CE</button>
```

Comment: Thanks for this. I wasn't too clear, I'm looking to delete a previous entry that is an operator with surrounding empty spaces. For example: 12" "+" "13. I currently have to press 'clear' 3 times to delete the operator and two empty spaces.

Answer (score 0):

CE stands for [Clear Entry](https://superuser.com/questions/449637/whats-the-difference-between-c-and-ce-functions-on-windows-calculator). In your case, based on your code, I think this should suffice:

```
deletebtn.addEventListener('click', () => {
    currentDisplay.textContent = "";
})
```

Comment: Thanks for this. I wasn't too clear, I'm looking to delete a previous entry that is an operator with surrounding empty spaces. For example: 12" "+" "13. I currently have to press 'clear' 3 times to delete the operator and two empty spaces.